# Apply the same function with multiple columns as inputs to multiple columns in R with tidyverse

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

As an example, I have the following data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(a1=1,a2=2,a3=3,b1=1,b2=2,b3=3)
```

I have a function:

```
fn <- function(x,y,z) x^y+(z-x)^(y-x)
```

I want the following:

```
df <- df %>% mutate(a=fn(a1,a2,a3),b=fn(b1,b2,b3))
```

The problem is, I have tons of triplets in my dataset, so it is not ideal to write them out one by one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would convert `df` to long format then use `lag` to create 3 columns then apply `fn()` on them

```r
library(tidyverse)

df_long <- df %>% 
  pivot_longer(everything(),
               names_to = c(".value", "set"),
               names_pattern = "(.)(.)")

df_longer <- df_long %>% 
  pivot_longer(-c(set),
               names_to = "key",
               values_to = "val") %>% 
  arrange(key)
df_longer
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#>   set   key     val
#>   <chr> <chr> <dbl>
#> 1 1     a         1
#> 2 2     a         2
#> 3 3     a         3
#> 4 1     b         1
#> 5 2     b         2
#> 6 3     b         3
```

`lag` then apply `fn()`, keep only non-NA `val_fn`

```r
df_longer <- df_longer %>% 
  group_by(key) %>% 
  mutate(val_lag1 = lag(val, n = 1),
         val_lag2 = lag(val, n = 2)) %>% 
  mutate(val_fn = fn(val_lag2, val_lag1, val)) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(val_fn))
df_longer
#> # A tibble: 2 x 6
#> # Groups:   key [2]
#>   set   key     val val_lag1 val_lag2 val_fn
#>   <chr> <chr> <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1 3     a         3        2        1      3
#> 2 3     b         3        2        1      3
```

<sup>Created on 2020-12-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Here are base R options using:

- `split.default` + `lapply` + `do.call`

```
cbind(
  df,
  lapply(
    split.default(df, gsub("\\d+", "", names(df))),
    function(x) do.call(fn, unname(x))
  )
)
```

- `reshape` + `lapply` + `do.call`

```
cbind(
  df,
  lapply(
    subset(
      reshape(
        setNames(df, gsub("(\\d+)$", "\\.\\1", names(df))),
        direction = "long",
        varying = 1:length(df)
      ),
      select = -c(time, id)
    ),
    function(x) do.call(fn, as.list(x))
  )
)
```

**Output**

```
  a1 a2 a3 b1 b2 b3 a b
1  1  2  3  1  2  3 3 3
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be easier/shorter to combine columns into their separate group and apply the function to each column.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = everything(), 
               names_to = '.value', 
               names_pattern = '([a-z]+)') %>%
  summarise(across(.fns = ~do.call(fn, as.list(.)))) -> result
result

#     a     b
#  <dbl> <dbl>
#1     3     3
```

You can bind the `result` to your original dataset if needed.

```
bind_cols(df, result)
#  a1 a2 a3 b1 b2 b3 a b
#1  1  2  3  1  2  3 3 3
```